# regarding classless inter domain routing

Tags: networking, network-programming, tcp

i want to know about the CIDR.and few good questions to practise so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Read wikipedia's [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) page.

An IP address can be thought of as having 2 parts, the network address followed by the host address. Routes in the internet address a specific network, and thus group together many hosts. For example, 66.11.0.0/16 addresses all hosts between 66.11.0.0 and 66.11.255.255 (the /16 states that the network prefix is 16 bits long).

Classful addressing divided the ip by octets into classes A, B, and C (with 1, 2, and 3 octets respectively, basically /8, /16, and /24). This resulted in routing tables being very large, as entries could only be grouped in those three tiers. CIDR was introduced in order to reduce the size of the routing tables. In essence, CIDR states that the network part can be a variable number of bits, and not necessarily octets. This allows for routes like 66.11.128.0/20, whereas in classful addressing, the networks would've had 16 C (/24) routes.